# Magento 2, how to get all product options with their price of configuration for view reorder by API?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, api, reorder

Using `Magento 2.2`, `API`, `Reorder`. I need to get all cart item information from **Product Detail** page by programmatically.

> Step 1: Click Reorder from **My Dashboard -> Recent Orders**
>   [image]

I need belove information **Programmatically**

> Step 2: Cart Item status which got from **Previous Ordered**
>   [image]

Comment: got any solution ?

Comment: Yes. I solved this problem.